# Partition table BSD

Tags: partitioning, mbr, bsd

I messed up the partition table of my HDD and i guess now its in the BSD format and windows/ubuntu both cannot read it. Does this mean I need to format my HDD and lose my entire file system or is there some way to get my files back(not using recovery software which would be my last option if nothing works)?

Thanks

Comment: "Does this mean I need to format my HDD and lose my entire file system or is there some way to get my files back"-- Not necessarily, what does gparted *exactly* says? if it's in BSD might just venture into getting a BSD distro, changes to the partition tables require the drive to be formatted.